# PDF Icon in announcement lists attached files

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom, xml, pdf, file-icons

I added the following line in the `DOCICON.XML` file and I get the PDF icon in my document lists, but not in Announcement lists that have a file attached or uploaded as a PDF.

`<Mapping Key="pdf" Value="icpdf.png" OpenControl=""/>`

PDF attached in announcement list

[image]

PDF in Document Library

[image]

I am using SharePoint 2010 Standard.

Answer (score 2):

The path to the icon is inserted at the time you created the post and unfortunately it is not dynamic. You have to edit the posts prior to adding the PDF icon and update the path to the proper icon image file. All new post after the PDF icon was added will show correctly.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint doesn't show icons for attachments. Are you doing something to force it to via SharePoint Designer?

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is in SharePoint 2010. [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/cPPqg.jpg) This is out of the box.

Comment: Ooo, I thought you were attaching to the item. I tested it out on mine as well and it works: http://screencast.com/t/dG1j9cWNZ. The path to my image is /_layouts/images/icpdf.png. This is odd since you can see it in the doc library... When did you apply the docicon.xml settings?

Comment: I did this a couple of days ago and have reset the IIS a couple times since then. BTW, the image doesn't end in PDF it actually does. I just edited the image and accidently left it out.

Comment: what do you mean by "BTW, the image doesn't end in PDF it actually does. I just edited the image and accidently left it out."

Comment: I added screenshots of the list and library examples.

Comment: how large of a farm is this? do you have multiple web front ends? did you make the same changes to all of them?

Comment: The farm is very simple. Just one front end and one SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart IIS?

in cmd , type "iisreset"

for my sharepoint, file is "pdf16.gif" and with resolution 16x16 pixel.my code is here :

```
<Mapping Value="pdf16.gif" Key="pdf"/>
```

try to replace png with gif.maybe it works.

Comment: It didn't affect the announcement list but made my document lists worse as it showed the broken image.

Comment: To clarify, the Value="xxx.gif" should be the actual image name you're using. behrouz's image is named differently than yours.

Comment: Obviously, I only changed .png to gif. and restarted the IIS and the ourcome in the anouncment list PDF attachment was the same as I have updated my original question and the document PDF item had a broken image.

Comment: you mean you only changed .png to .gif not convert ? you should convert Png to Gif not changing name of file format, but if you converted then i have no idea for solution.

Comment: Well, I converted the 16x16 image from jpg to gif, updated the DOCICON.XML file to reflect the new file and reset the IIS and got the same result as my original post.